# Generating a nested route with Ember-appkit-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to generate a nested resource with ember-appkit-rails but I'm not sure if it's possible. For instance I'm trying to make a surveys route that has questions, so I used the generator like this.

```
rails g scaffold survey title:string question:references date:date --ember
```

And them I'm doing:

```
rails g scaffold questions questions:string survey:references answer:references
```

And then trying to fiddle around with what the generates to make it work, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I go to the survey route saying it can't find the App.Question model. I'm not sure how to hook these up manually in rails because I'm new to rails.

Comment: Might need a bit more code to go on. Maybe question model? Router? What error are you getting? Is the Rails console giving you an error or is your browser not rendering?